# Converting An Image To A Buffer In Java

Tags: java, opengl-es, libgdx

I am trying to implement some simple 3D functionality into a game I am currently developing.  I am utilizing the **LibGDX Game Engine** to accomplish this goal, as it seemed to integrate nicely with OpenGL ES, however have run into a problem stemming from my inability to figure out how to create a simple `Buffer` object from an image in Java.

### The Problem

The goal for me is to have a cube spinning around in 3D space, with some textures on it.  The problem is that, although I managed to render the cube and have it spin, I cannot seem to find any tutorials, code examples, or documentation on how to actually decode an image to a `Buffer` in order to texture the cube.  I have found quite a few examples illustrating how to do this in Android, however this limits you to having to use the `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(<your_image here>)` method in the Android SDK, which is not an option for me as I am trying to allow my code to be portable to many platforms.

It is for this reason that I have came to the conclusion that I must somehow find a way to decode an image (a `.bmp` file) into a `Buffer` in order to leverage the `Gdx.gl10.glTexImage2D()` method that I found packaged with OpenGL ES.

### What I Have Tried So Far

I have pursued numerous alternatives to try find a solution, some which include:

- Leveraging the `Texture.bind()` method embedded in the `Texture` class that comes with the LibGDX package.
- Trying to decode the image using the Java [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageReader.html) package.
- Using some other decoding tools such as the [image4j](http://image4j.sourceforge.net/) library.

### Some Code

Here is some of the code that I am using to render the Cube.  Lots of the OpenGL "switch-flipping" is omitted for the sake of clarity, so if you think I have missed something, please post a comment and I will confirm if it is simply in another part of another class.

I know that this code will be rather stifling to sift through, so I have done my best to comment it as necessary.

Note that this code represents my current implementation, and is the code associated with the "Debugging Information" section below.

```
public void draw(){

    // This is used to hold the OpenGL pointer to the texture      
    int[] textures = new int[1];

    // Tells the GPU to render the vertices in a clockwise manner   
    Gdx.gl10.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);

    // Informs OpenGL of the location of the vertices
    Gdx.gl10.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mVertexBuffer);

    // Bind the texture pointer in OpenGL to the texture
    Gdx.gl10.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    // This is the function I found in LibGDX that I think I am supposed to use?
    mTexture.bind();

    // Some "switch-flipping" in OpenGL
    Gdx.gl10.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
            GL10.GL_NEAREST);

    Gdx.gl10.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
            GL10.GL_LINEAR);

    Gdx.gl10.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
            GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    Gdx.gl10.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
            GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    Gdx.gl10.glTexEnvf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,
            GL10.GL_REPLACE);

    // This tells OpenGL to assign my Texture to the 3D Image
    Gdx.gl10.glTexImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL10.GL_RGB, 256, 256, 0, GL10.GL_RGB, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mTexture);

    // Finally, this draws the objects to the screen
    Gdx.gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mIndexBuffer);
}
```

### My Question

How do you decode an image directly into a `Buffer` in Java?  If this cannot be done, then how should I be going about trying to texture my 3D objects in LibGDX?  Are there any other resources I should consult?

### Debugging Information

*Last Updated: 19 Mar 2013 12:45PM EST*

Here is some information related to the current debugging process of my application.  I will update this as I progress through this issue:

- At the moment, when I run my application, I receive an error `Invalid memory access of location 0x0 rip=0x11dc77564`, perhaps this implementation is the correct one, and I am just missing some syntax elsewhere?
- I am currently investigating [this](http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=4552&p=21913&hilit=3D%20Cube%20texture#p21913) additional resource that I found after sifting through some forums.
- It would appear that the `Mesh` object would be the correct route here.  I will try to pursue this implementation and update regarding my results!  I was unable to locate this before as it is considered "deprecated" by the LibGDX team, so I am unsure if this will be replaced soon.

### Supplemental Information

Some things that should be taken into consideration when answering my question are:

- It should be noted that I am doing this using the [LibGDX Game Engine](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/), and for that reason, I will also be posting on their forums regarding this issue.
- Further, there seem to be many ways to get a `BufferedImage` from the Image, however there is then no way to extract a `Buffer` from that `BufferedImage`.  Am I simply overlooking something glaringly obvious here?  Are `BufferedImage`s really all I should need?
- I would prefer not to just include the Android SDK in my build path and use their simple `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(<your_image_here>)` method.
- I am currently trying to implement this using OpenGL ES 1.0 for compatibility reasons.

Comment: +1 for doing your research and for explaining your situation well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to avoid the raw OpenGL texture and buffer APIs, and stick to the Libgdx `Mesh` and `Texture` wrappers.  They hide a bunch of the OpenGL details.  Of course, if you're interested in learning about the OpenGL details, this won't really help.  (But perhaps you can get things working with the Libgdx APIs, and then look through their source to see what is really happening).

The first step is to make sure your `Mesh` (or your raw `mVertexBuffer` OpenGL vertex list if you're not using a `Mesh`) contains valid (u, v) texture coordinates with each vertex.  These coordinates will refer to the "current" texture at render time. See https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/MeshColorTexture#Texture.

First, define your Mesh to include texture information with each vertex:

```
mesh = new Mesh(true, 3, 3, 
            new VertexAttribute(Usage.Position, 3, "a_position"),
            new VertexAttribute(Usage.ColorPacked, 4, "a_color"),
            new VertexAttribute(Usage.TextureCoordinates, 2, "a_texCoords"));
```

(This mesh has color data too, but you can leave off the line with "a_color" if you don't want to blend in raw color data.)

The other prepatory step is to load your texture file into a Libgdx texture.  Assuming the file is packaged in the standard "assets" location, you should just be able to load it with the relative path:

```
Texture texture = new Texture("path/to/image.bmp");
```

Libgdx can generally load and parse BMP, PNG, and JPEG file formats.  For other formats, I think you'd need to create a `Pixmap` object yourself, and then plug that into a `Texture`.

Second, make sure each vertex has (u,v) texture coordinates associated with it:

```
mesh.setVertices(new float[] { -0.5f, -0.5f, 0, Color.toFloatBits(255, 0, 0, 255), 0, 1,
                                0.5f, -0.5f, 0, Color.toFloatBits(0, 255, 0, 255), 1, 1
                                0, 0.5f, 0, Color.toFloatBits(0, 0, 255, 255), 0.5f, 0 });
```

Each line above defines the "(x, y, z, rgba, u, v)" for each vertex.  (The "rgba" is the whole color squashed into a single float.)

At this point you have defined a `Mesh` with a `Color` information and texture (u, v) coordinates.

The second step is, during the `render` call, to bind your texture, so the (u, v) coordinates in the `Mesh` have something to reference:

```
texture.bind();
mesh.render(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

You don't need to direclty use any of the OpenGL texture or vertex APIs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  As you can see from my updated "Debugging Information" I also found this document on their forums!  For some reason it was deprecated, though, more than likely because they are working on their new 3D API.  I appreciate the detailed and extensive response explaining how to implement the `Mesh` class, though, and I will be utilizing this heavily in my next attempts!

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the Libgdx 3D APIs, other than knowing that they are in flux still.  Whatever they do, they will eventually boil down to a list of vertices like this, so you shouldn't be too far off.